# Do you have to use JQuery Validation Plugin validate() on a form element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a master page and in that master page I have:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">             
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

My question is in my child pages do I need to use the form element to implement the validate method?

For example script in child form:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: "required",
            comment: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter a name",
            email: "Please enter an email",
            comment: "Enter a comment"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

The child form html is:

```
<div id="commentForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
        <input id="cname" class="form-control" name="name" minlength="2" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
        <input id="cemail" class="form-control" type="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
        <input id="curl" class="form-control" type="url" name="url">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
        <textarea id="ccomment" class="form-control" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

`$("#commentForm").validate` will not work. However if I switch it to `$("#form1").validate` it will.

Since I can't nest forms is it possible to implement the validate method on anything other then the parent form element?

Comment: jQuery only validates at the "form" level I think.  You can include one form within another.

Comment: @Dean.DePue `You can include one form within another` No you cannot have nested forms

Comment: @A.Wolff - I've done many times with MVC...

Comment: @Dean.DePue That's just invalid HTML markup and anyway AFAIK nested form's content would be unwraped by browser parser

Comment: @A.Wolff - I do it all the time with partial views inside other views, each of them with a different form name.  The validation works just fine.

Comment: @Dean.DePue That's strange imo. You can see here how is it parsed: https://jsfiddle.net/31rcburh/

Comment: @A.Wolff - you are right - what happens in my projects (I just checked what the DOM looks like) is when I bring up a partial view I show it most of the time in a jQuery dialog.  In the DOM it shows both forms, one on top of the other, not nested.  And the function to validate the partial works just fine when I define the form name like $("#formPlug").valid().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> .validate()
>
> Description: Validates the selected form.

So yes it assumed that the selected element is a `form`

Comment: So if I have a popup modal (bootstrap) I would have to tie each modal to the parent form element?